# How to Change the status voice msg of Bluetooth module

Tags: audio, integrated-circuit, bluetooth

I just buy a Bluetooth module XY-BT-MINI, when I turn it on, it says "The Bluetooth device is ready to pair". But I don´t like the voice. I just want a connected sound,

- Can I replace the voice msg with connected sound ?
- Can I change the name of the Bluetooth device.

Link: http://www.ebay.com/itm/351804941744?rmvSB=true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the actual built-in voice is likely not feasible.

However, you could *intercept* the voice with your own audio. This could be done by switching the audio output with your own, and then switching back to the original signal. You'd need an additional audio driver with stored audio.

If it's just the power on voice you want to change, it would be simple to detect when the device receives power and then switch the audio signals.
Detecting other status changes like device pairing and such may also be possible by monitoring pins on the bluetooth IC, (you'd have to check the datasheet).

A small microprocessor would be well suited for monitoring and switching.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCvoT7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

*I bought a new Bluetooth IC*

No you didn't, you bought a **Bluetooth Audio module**. The ICs are the 2 black components on the module.

*Can the voice be changed?*

Yes **if** you were the company making the IC which contains the voice or you have all needed information including source code of the data in that IC so that you can recompile the data and flash it into the IC.

But you probably do not have access to all this so then the answer is **No**, you cannot change the voice. It's a cheap Chinese module, what did you expect ?

Comment: These often used to have an external SPI flash presumably containing the messages... but the linked product appears not to, just a class D audio amp and another IC that is presumably everything else.